# 403 response when trying to redirect using nginx to API Gateway

Tags: nginx, aws-api-gateway

I have the following API: `https://kdhdh64g.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/user/${user-id}` which proxies to a `Lambda` function.

When the user hits `/user/1234` the function checks if 1234 exists and return the info for that user or a redirection to /users

What I want is to create is a redirection with `nginx`. For SEO, I want a simple 302: `return 302 the-url`. If someone goes to `mySite.com` it should redirect to `https://kdhdh64g.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev`

No matter what I do, I always receive a `403` with the following:

```
x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
x-amz-apigw-id: QrFd6GByoJHGf1g=
x-cache: Error from cloud-front
via: 1.1 dfg35721fhfsgdv36vs52fa785f5g.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

I will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the reverse proxy set up in nginx, add the below line in the config file and restart or reload the nginx configuration.

```
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue trying to run a proxy on Nginx towards an API Gateway which triggers a Lambda function on AWS. When I read the error logs on Nginx, I noticed that it had to do with the SSL version which Nginx was using to connect to API Gateway, the error was the following:

```
*1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream
```

I managed to fix it by adding this line:

```
proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3;
```

I attach the complete Nginx configuration in case anyone wants to build a static IP proxy on Nginx that redirects traffic towards a Lambda function:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name $yourservername;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://$lambdafunctionaddress;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3;
}
ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/.ssl/ca-chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/.ssl/server.key;
```

}

Also it is important to consider that all required information must be included on the request:

```
curl -X POST https://$yourservername/env/functionname -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-api-key: <yourapikey>" -d $payload
```